# How to remove the .active class from a <div> when closing a dropdown? jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Well, he tried to make that once the drop-down menu is closed, the .active class (blue color) is removed to show the original color.
Currently it is only removed when I select another `<div>`. I removed the .active class from the html thinking that maybe that was the problem, but I think it's something from the js code. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(".name").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".submenu").slideToggle();
});

$(".item .name").click(function(){
  $(".name").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});

$(".submenu li").click(function(){
  $("li").removeClass("active2");
  $(this).addClass("active2");
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}
.item {
  width: 350px;
}
.name {
  background: #323232;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item:hover .name, .active {
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: blue;
}
.submenu {
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
.submenu li {
  padding: 5px;
}
li:hover, .active2 {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name">Name One<span>➕</span></div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name">Name Two<span>➕</span></div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood exactly what you meant this might be the solution for you. You need to check if the clicked item already has an active class and add/remove the class to the active element.

Additionally, you can collapse the selected open element on Click of its child element.

Something like this:

```
$('.name').click(function () {
  const current = $(this);
  
  current.next('.submenu').slideToggle();

  if (current.hasClass('active')) {
    current.removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.item .name').removeClass('active'); // First remove active class from all dropdown
    current.addClass('active');
  }
});

$('.submenu li').click(function () {
  $('li').removeClass('active2');
  $(this).addClass('active2');

  $(this).parent().slideToggle(); // Close parent on click
  $(this).parent().prev().removeClass('active'); // Remove parent sibling active class
});
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for, but now the problem is that every time I click on an <li> element the menu closes and I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Glad could help you, you can remove these 2 lines of code for the issue you mentioned.
`$(this).parent().slideToggle();`
`$(this).parent().prev().removeClass('active');`